# Rendering only one child component after state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, vis.js

I have built a React component which has two children: one displays a graph (vis.js) and when the user hovers over a node in the graph, the main component is made aware of this by a state change. The only child using this state is a div (sibling to the graph).

However, when the state changes, all children (including the graph) are re-rendered. I do not want to render the graph every time I hover over a node, just its sibling.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
...

const Graph = (props) => {

  ...

  const [nodeName, setNodeName] = useState("");

  function handleHoverEvent(node) {
    if (nodeName !== node) {
      setNodeName(node);
    }
  }

  function makeNodes() {
    ...
  }

  function makeEdges() {
    ...
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Vis
        nodes={makeNodes()}
        edges={makeEdges()}
        OnHover={handleHoverEvent}
      />
      <NameDisplay name={nodeName} />
    </div>
  );
}

...



export default Graph;
```

`makeNodes()` and `makeEdges()` do not depend on the state in any way.

How can I prevent the graph from being re-rendered every time? All I need to do is "shovel" data from one child to another, while only updating one of them.

Comment: Did you try with useMemo() ?

Comment: You can `memo` the `Vis` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All it took was to convert all components to ES6 classes. This is described here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class

I did not even have to specify a [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) method.

Comment: Using memo did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `React.memo()`, `React.useCallback` for avoiding re-rendering stuff in react component. [Avoiding React component re-renders with React.memo](https://aheadcreative.co.uk/articles/avoiding-react-component-re-renders-with-react-memo/)

Example :

**Button**

```
import React from "react";

interface IProps {
  handleClick: () => void;
  children: any;
}

function Button({ handleClick, children }: IProps) {
  console.log("Rendering button - ", children);
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>{children}</button>;
}

export default React.memo(Button);
```

**Count**

```
    import React from "react";
    import Button from './Button'
    
    interface IProps {
      text: any;
      count: any;
      handleClick: () => void;
      children: any;
    }
    
    function Count({ text, count, handleClick, children }: IProps) {
      console.log(`Rendering ${text}`);
      return (
        <div>
        <div>
          {text} - {count}
        </div>
        <Button handleClick={handleClick}>{children}</Button>
        </div>
      );
    }

export default React.memo(Count);
```

**ParentComponent**

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import Count from "./Count";

export const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [age, setAge] = useState(25);
  const [salary, setSalary] = useState(50000);

//   const incrementAge = () => {
//      setAge(age + 1)
//   }

//   const incrementSalary = () => {
//      setSalary(salary + 1000)
//   }

  const incrementAge = useCallback(() => {
    setAge(age + 1);
  }, [age]);

  const incrementSalary = useCallback(() => {
    setSalary(salary + 1000);
  }, [salary]);

  return (
    <>
      <Count text="Age" count={age} handleClick={incrementAge}>
        Increment Age
      </Count>
      <Count text="Salary" count={salary} handleClick={incrementSalary}>
        Increment Salary
      </Count>
    </>
  );
};
```